# Can I change a model from embedded to referenced without losing data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I made a bad decision as I was designing a MongoDB database to embed a model rather than reference it in an associated model. Now I need to make the embedded model a referenced model, but there is already a healthy amount of data in the database (or document?).

I'm using Mongoid, so I reasoned I can just change `embedded_in` to `referenced_in`. Before I start, I figured I'd ask people who know better than I do. How can I transition the embedded data already in the database to the document for the associated model.

```
class Building

  embeds_many :landlords

..
end

class Landlord 
  embedded_in :building
...
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - Incrementally.

1. Create a copy of Landlord, name it Landlord2.
2. Make it referenced in Building.
3. Copy all data from Landlord to Landlord2.
4. Delete Landlord.
5. Rename Landlord2 to Landlord.

Users should not be able to CRUD Landlord during steps 3-5 (ideally). You still can get away with only locking CRUD on 4-5. Just make sure you make all updates that happened during copying, before removing Landlords.

Answer (score 0):

Just chan ging the model like you have above will not work, the old data will still be in a different strucutre in the db.

Very similar the previous answer, one of the things I have done to do this migration before is to do it dynamically, while the system is running and being used by the users.

I had the data layer separated from the logic, so it let me add some preprocessors and inject code to do the following.

Lets say we start with the old datamodel, then release new code that does the following:
On every access to the document, you would have to check whether the embedded property exists, if it does, create a new entry associated as a reference and save to the database and delete the embedded property from the documents. Once this is done for a couple of days, a lot of my data got migrated and then I just had to run a similar script for everything that was not touched, made the job of migrating the data much easier and simpler and I did not have to run long running scripts or get the system offline to perform the conversion.

You may not ha ve that requirement, so Pick accordingly.